# Parse JSON to a dataframe

Tags: json, r, dataframe

Not sure how to do this:

I have a something stored like this (in `a`):

```
[
  "MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.0000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.499989970587194, -95.0000000372529 40.499989970587194)))"
]

typeof(a) # prints "character"
class(a)  # prints "json"
```

And I would like to convert it to a data.frame that looks like this (no need to round the numbers, it was just easier to type  that)

```
  X1  X2
1 -95 40
2 -94 40
3 -94 40
4 -95 40
```

I tried

```
a.df<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(a))
```

but that prints

```
 V1
1 [\n  "MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.0000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.499989970587194, -95.0000000372529 40.499989970587194)))"\n]\n
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON at all. Are you sure there isn't some other name for this file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(sf)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

x <- fromJSON('[
  "MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.0000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.499989970587194, -95.0000000372529 40.499989970587194)))"
]')

map(x, st_as_sfc) %>%
  map(~as.data.frame(.[[1]][[1]]))
## [[1]]
##      X1       X2
## 1 -95.0 40.99999
## 2 -94.5 40.99999
## 3 -94.5 40.49999
## 4 -95.0 40.49999
```

Now:

```
wkt2geojson('[
  "MULTIPOLYGON (((-95.0000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.999989970587194, -94.5000000372529 40.499989970587194, -95.0000000372529 40.499989970587194)))"
]')
```

also kinda works but tosses warnings.

Knowing the actual source that created this WKT in such a configuration wld be helpful